# Grpc server with async and sync services at the same time

Tags: c++, grpc

I need to be able to serve responses for some particular requests from the main thread, while the rest can arrive from any thread. With that in mind,
I created a GRPC server which has 2 services, one is implemented as an AsyncService, and the other as a sync service.

However, when adding a completion queue, the sync service **no longer responds to requests.**

```
    builder.RegisterService(this); // this inherits from Service (sync)
    builder.RegisterService(&m_service); // m_services is an AsyncService 
    m_mainThreadQueue = builder.AddCompletionQueue();
    m_server = std::unique_ptr<Server>(builder.BuildAndStart());
    {
        (new GrabSnapshotCallData(this, &m_service, m_mainThreadQueue.get()))->Proceed();
    }
    m_server->Wait();
```

Adding the completion queue makes the sync service no longer response to requests.
I couldn't find much information about this particular topic anywhere, so perhaps it is not really supported in grpc.

So, is there a way to have both async and sync services simultaneously on the same server? If not, what should I do to emulate that behavior

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior. I modified the gRPC sync greeter server example to add a no-op async service, added a CQ to the builder, and ran the server with a simple client. The sync service worked as expected. It might help to simplify your example, or to start from the basic provided helloworld example and build it up until you can reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple c++ example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include "gRpcAutoGenerated/hellostreamingworld.grpc.pb.h"

class ServiceImpl_sync : public hellostreamingworld::MultiGreeter::Service
{
public:
  grpc::Status sayHello_Sync(grpc::ServerContext *context, const hellostreamingworld::HelloRequest *request, grpc::ServerWriter<hellostreamingworld::HelloReply> *responsWriter) override
  {
    std::cout << "sayHello_Sync" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      hellostreamingworld::HelloReply newHelloReply;
      newHelloReply.set_message("Hello Sync " + request->name() + " " + std::to_string(i));
      responsWriter->Write(newHelloReply);
    }
    return grpc::Status::OK;
  };
};

class sayHello_aSync_handler final
{

public:
  sayHello_aSync_handler(hellostreamingworld::MultiGreeter::WithAsyncMethod_sayHello_aSync<ServiceImpl_sync> *service, grpc::ServerCompletionQueue *cq)
  {
    service_ = service;
    cq_ = cq;
    responsWriter_ = new grpc::ServerAsyncWriter<hellostreamingworld::HelloReply>(&context_);
    service_->RequestsayHello_aSync(&context_, &request_, responsWriter_, cq_, cq_, this);
    state_ = CallState::Status_Write;
    cycleCounter_ = 0;
  }

  void Procss()
  {
    std::cout << "sayHello_aSync_handler::Procss" << std::endl;
    if (state_ == CallState::Status_Write)
    {
      cycleCounter_++;
      hellostreamingworld::HelloReply newHelloReply;
      newHelloReply.set_message("Hello aSync " + request_.name() + " " + std::to_string(cycleCounter_));
      if (cycleCounter_ < 10)
      {
        responsWriter_->Write(newHelloReply, this);
      }
      else
      {
        state_ = CallState::Status_Finish;
        responsWriter_->Finish(grpc::Status::OK, this);
      }
    }
  }

  enum CallState
  {
    Status_Write,
    Status_Finish
  };

  hellostreamingworld::MultiGreeter::WithAsyncMethod_sayHello_aSync<ServiceImpl_sync> *service_;
  grpc::ServerCompletionQueue *cq_;
  grpc::ServerContext context_;
  hellostreamingworld::HelloRequest request_;
  grpc::ServerAsyncWriter<hellostreamingworld::HelloReply> *responsWriter_;
  int cycleCounter_;
  CallState state_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");
  grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
  builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
  
  ServiceImpl_sync SyncService;
  hellostreamingworld::MultiGreeter::WithAsyncMethod_sayHello_aSync<ServiceImpl_sync> aSyncService;
  builder.RegisterService(&aSyncService);
  
  std::unique_ptr<grpc::ServerCompletionQueue> cq = builder.AddCompletionQueue();
  std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server = builder.BuildAndStart();

  std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

  new sayHello_aSync_handler(&aSyncService, cq.get());

  void *got_tag = nullptr;
  bool ok = false;
  while (true)
  {
    std::cerr << "Blocked by cq->Next" << std::endl;
    if (!cq->Next(&got_tag, &ok))
    {
      std::cerr << "Server stream closed. Quitting" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (ok)
    {
      static_cast<sayHello_aSync_handler *>(got_tag)->Procss();
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

hellostreamingworld.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "ex.grpc";
option objc_class_prefix = "HSW";

package hellostreamingworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service MultiGreeter {
  // Sends multiple greetings
  rpc sayHello_Sync (HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply) {}
  rpc sayHello_aSync (HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name and how many greetings
// they want.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
  string num_greetings = 2;
}

// A response message containing a greeting
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```